# Dissolve function for selected polygons in a layer in QGIS 3.3

Tags: dissolve

Im using QGIS 3.3 and am trying to dissolve selected polygons in a layer. In the dissolve tool I am unable to select ' selected features only'. Even if i manually select the polygons and run the dissolve function, all the polygons in the layer dissolves to one big polygon. I am new to QGIS.

Comment: Have you made sure the selected polygons are on the layer you're trying to dissolve?

Comment: You're new to QGIS and installed version 3.3? Really? You rather mean 3.30? Please post a screenshot of the whole QGIS window (don't crop any parts) and with selected polygons when you want to dissolve.